# Fix on active in firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

Faced a small problem in firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/3jmeS/, when clicking on the link `active` style fires on all element, but i need only on current. Is there a fix?

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <div id="left-nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#left-nav {
    float: left;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 38px;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    min-width: 600px;
}

#left-nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 12px;
}

#left-nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 0 11px;
}

#left-nav li a:active{
    position: relative;
    top:1px;
}

#left-nav li.active a{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: @Andy In safari and ie it works normally for each.

Comment: @Andy It could do if you were linking to different parts of the same page

Comment: I tried it in the fiddle and it didn't differentiate them

Comment: @Pete in what firefox version?

Comment: all of the anchor elements have <code>display:block;</code>....and <code>.active a</code> has it as well....so you're not going to see any change. i'm curious to what you are seeing in other browsers.